# Google Map Address Geocoding API not working

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, geocoding

I am new to the GCP. I have created a project in the Google Cloud Platform and enabled Geocoding API and Static Map API.

> I had free trial but when more requests come, Geocoding API shows **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** reached. Therefore, I enabled the billing to that project so it is solved but the billing account has own its some quota or threshold for the requests.

Because if I reached over that threshold, it says again **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**. How can I extend this with having current billing (no extra charges)?

If this is not possible, what the billing account means.

And I received many time 403 response code in the GCP Geocoding API Logs rather than 200 response code. And I don't know why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

it counts the per second query limits. consider that.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you have $300 (usable for GCP Products) one time credit upon activating your Billing account plus monthly recurring of $200 credit (exclusive for Maps API only), if you haven't exhausted this credit then maybe you just need to adjust your quota higher in order to avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, but if your project is already in production, then you might need to upgrade your billing account.

Upgrading your billing account will allow you to exceed your quota, however extra charges will occur, but you can set limit to your API usage to prevent excess bill.
You may refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) to learn on how to edit your quota and learn on Capping API Usage.